# Failed to compile after npm start in create-react-kotlin-app module

Tags: reactjs, npm, kotlin

I am trying to run `create-react-kotlin-app` module using `npm` but it gives me this error:

> Failed to compile
>
> multi ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
>   ./node_modules/react-scripts-kotlin/config/polyfills.js kotlinApp
>   Module not found: Syntax/Users/amin/package.json (directory
>   description file): SyntaxError: /Users/amin/package.json (directory
>   description file): SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Although I have just followed these instructions:

1. `npm install -g create-react-kotlin-app`
2. `create-react-kotlin-app my-app`
3. `cd my-app`
4. `npm start`

Note: I could successfully run `create-react-app` module with no errors. My JDK is also 1.8.111 in case it matters. Does anyone know why do I get such an error and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe run `npm install` between 2 and 3 Step 2 should be `npx create-react-kotlin-app my-app`

Comment: @HMR, do i need to do 'cd my-app' before that?

Comment: Yes, you can also create an app with `create-react-app my-app --scripts-version react-scripts-kotlin` according to ]the documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app). The docs say that npm install is not needed (maybe start will take care of that).

Comment: no luck even with 'create-react-app my-app --scripts-version react-scripts-kotlin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after uninstalling Node from my MacBook and installing it again. follow these steps to uninstall Node completely: [How to uninstall Node from MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)
Then I installed Node again using `brew install node` (Don't forget `brew update` before that)